# How can I recolor shapes in a binary image for indexing (floodfill)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have created a binary image with thresholding. How can change the color of the white shapes as in the picture below to make them indexable?

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
void threshold()
{
    cv::Mat src_8uc3_img = cv::imread("images/train.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); // load color image from file system to Mat variable, this will be loaded using 8 bits (uchar)

    if (src_8uc3_img.empty()) {
        printf("Unable to read input file (%s, %d).", __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    }

    double thresh = 0;
    double maxValue = 255;

    cv::Mat thresh_holding = src_8uc3_img.clone();
    cv::Mat indexing = src_8uc3_img.clone();
    cv::imshow("Train", src_8uc3_img);

    for (int y = 0; y < thresh_holding.rows ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < thresh_holding.cols ; x++) {
            uchar thX = thresh_holding.at<uchar>(y, x);
            if (thX < 128 ) {
                thresh_holding.at<uchar>(y, x) = thresh;
            }
            else if (thX>128){
                thresh_holding.at<uchar>(y, x) = maxValue;
            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("ThreshHolding", thresh_holding);

    cv::waitKey(0); // wait until keypressed

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i have the picture the one only has white shapes i need to change their color to the color what i want.

Comment: @akglali Check the answer that now also includes exampe code. Accept if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: it's "thresholding", not "thresh holding". It means to set/apply a threshold, not holding a thresh, whatever it means.

What you want is clearly finding the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) of your image. Unless you want to learn basic image processing, you first use the [`threshold()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) function. Then **don't use `findContours()`/`drawContours()`**, because they are slow. If you want different connected components use [`connectedComponents()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5): it's fast and you get a different label for each component. Coloring is up to you, based on the index.

Inspired by Alex Alex Python answer, here you can find the C++ version:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    using namespace cv;
    // Read image
    Mat1b img = imread("input.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    // Make sure it's binary
    threshold(img, img, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    // Extract connected components
    Mat1i labels;
    int nlabels = connectedComponents(img, labels);
    // Make the connected components from 0 to 255 (assume less than 256 labels)
    img = labels * 255 / nlabels;
    // Make the labels colored
    Mat3b colored, output;
    applyColorMap(img, colored, COLORMAP_JET);
    // Mask background with zeros in original image
    colored.copyTo(output, img);
    // Write output
    imwrite("output.png", output);
}
```

The only difference is that I specified the type for the images in order to have the assignment to `img` also cast to 8 bpp. And the typed `Mat`s are much nicer to use.

Answer (score 3):

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
a=cv2.imread('P.png')
b=cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
b=cv2.threshold(b, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 
lbl=cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(b, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
im_lbl=np.uint8(255*lbl[1]/lbl[0])
out_img=cv2.applyColorMap(im_lbl, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
out_img=cv2.bitwise_and(out_img, a)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', out_img)
```

Result:
[image]